# how to add 'Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content' via xcconfig files

Tags: ios, xcode, xcconfig

Is there a way to add a (external) library, dylib, via an xcconfig file?

For an iOS app, in section mentioned in below image:

[image: This section in Xcode]

I tried it with `FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH` and `LD_DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME` , and I can make my app build, so it finds the required dylib. But the dylib is not added to the simulator / app, so running the app fails with an `image not found exception`.

If I add the dylib via XCode under the 'add Framewoks ... this works, but since I have no fat binaries but separate builds, I need to specify different libs (same name different folder)